# make third_party

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm following [Google's OR-Tools instructions](http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/wiki/AGettingStarted#Troubleshooting) and reading this instruction:

```
> "Then you can download all dependencies and build them using:
> 
>    make third_party"
```

What is this make command? Should I run it from Windows command prompt? Where is this third_party file located?

Sorry for this basic question. I'm new to this realm.

Answer (score 2):

That page seems very clear to me.

> **Please make sure that svn.exe, nmake.exe and cl.exe are in your path.**

You need to do exactly that. `nmake.exe` implements the `make` command, from the sound of things. As to where you should run this command, run it, as the page says, from the terminal in the Tools menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is I don't find "terminal" under Tools in VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

**NAME**

```
make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs
```

**SYNOPSIS**

```
make [ -f makefile ] [ option ] ... target ...
```

Simply put make is a compilation tool, the Make command is a command used in Linux to  'make' all necessary recompilations. Make requires a configuration file. Once this file is constructed for your project, you usually type make to build the changed files.

Take a look at this link for some `make` examples.
http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/01/31/make_intro.html

As per the link you provided, the instructions are straight forward:

**Compiling libraries**

All build rules use make (gnu make), even on windows. A `make.exe` binary is provided in the tools sub-directory; They are providing you with the `make.exe`, which means that in Windows you can use `svn.exe` to execute the following commands, just make sure you are within the path that includes the make binary.

If you do not find `svn.exe`, please install a svn version that offers the command line tool.
http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

Just execute the following commands to build the dependencies:

```
make
```

*To compile in debug mode while in windows, use the following:*

```
make DEBUG="/Od /Zi" all
```

*If you need to clean everything and do it again, run:*

```
make clean
```

This will clean all downloaded sources, all compiled dependencies, and Makefile.local. It is useful to get a clean state, or if you have added an archive in dependencies.archives.

Finally, to compile the library run:

```
make all
```

When everything is compiled, you will find under or-tools/bin and or-tools/lib:

```
some static libraries (libcp.a, libutil.a and libbase.a, and more)
One binary per C++ example (e.g. nqueens)
C++ wrapping libraries (pywrapcp.so, linjniwrapconstraint_solver.so)
Java jars (com.google.ortools.constraintsolver.jar...)
C# assemblies
```

**Then we can edit the MakeFile.local**

First off, download Python 2.7 and JDK 7, install them.

Edit Makefile.local to point to the correct Python and Java installation. For instance, on my system, it is:

```
WINDOWS_JDK_DIR = c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02
WINDOWS_PYTHON_VERSION = 27
WINDOWS_PYTHON_PATH = C:\\python27
```

**Afterwards, to use python, you need to install google-apputils.**

```
  cd dependencies/sources/google-apputils
  c:\python27\python.exe setup.py install
```